# Selenium: Clicking link and alert acting weird (flashing then disappearing)

Tags: firefox, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, alert

I'm writing an automated test against a Salesforce site. I'm using Firefox version 21.0 and Selenium version 2.33.0.

During the test, I have a couple of alerts to deal with (with one "okay" button) and do so successfully. The alerts behaves normally.

Later in the test, in a table, there is a delete link. When it is clicked, an alert appears saying "Are you sure?" with two options, OK and Cancel. Clicking OK should delete that row in the table.

But when I run the automated test, after clicking on the link, the alert very quickly flashes on and then disappears. The row has not been deleted. It is there and has a blue background (as it does when the mouse is hovered over the row). The popup disappearing is nothing to do with the code that follows clicking the link, as I have tried putting a big sleep in between and it still happens.

I am running the test in Firefox, could it be an issue with firefox? I tried running it in Chrome instead, but then the test keeps failing at an earlier point because it cant find an element which firefox can.

Below is the method I run to handle alerts. But I don't think the problem is to do with this, because it happens before this code is run. This method runs immediately after the clicking of the link...

```
private void acceptAlert() {
    String mainWindow = webdriver.getWindowHandle();
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webdriver, 20);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
    Alert alert = webdriver.switchTo().alert();
    alert.accept();
    webdriver.switchTo().window(mainWindow);
}
```

Comment: version of selenium, firefox?

Comment: Sorry. Its selenium 2 webdriver. Firefox version 21.0.

Comment: version of selenium jar file? is it selenium 2.33.0? firefox version?

Comment: Selenium JAR file version is 2.32.0

Comment: firefox browser version pls...

Comment: Yep, Firefox browser version is 21.0

Comment: Download the latest selenium jar file from [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/files/selenium-java-2.33.0.zip)

. selenium 2.32.0 supports only till Firefox 20. That could be the culprit.

Comment: Sure. Try that and let us know if the issue still exists.

Comment: I have just tried it with selenium 2.33.0 and the issue does still exist. But I've just noticed something in the console...

[main] WARN net.thucydides.core.webdriver.WebDriverFacade - Failed to take screenshot - driver closed already? (Modal dialog present: Are you sure?

It does look like any other alert... could this problem be to do with the modal dialog? Is a modal dialog different to an alert? But again, it closes when I click on the delete link, before running the code to handle an alert.

Comment: can you show the alert handling code that you are using to handle the confirmation box when you click delete link?

Comment: Sure... the code for clicking the link is ordersRLSteps.clickDeleteByIndex(0);    (this just finds the element and clicks on it. Then the alert appears and disappears. Then I have the following method):

`code`    private void acceptAlert() {
        String mainWindow = webdriver.getWindowHandle();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webdriver, 20);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
        Alert alert = webdriver.switchTo().alert();
        alert.accept();
        webdriver.switchTo().window(mainWindow);
    }`code`

Comment: Sorry, messed up the formatting on that last post. Heres the code:
`private void acceptAlert() { String mainWindow = webdriver.getWindowHandle(); WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webdriver, 20); wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent()); Alert alert = webdriver.switchTo().alert(); alert.accept(); webdriver.switchTo().window(mainWindow); }`

Comment: @Chris It would help if you edit your question to include the extra information; if it's scattered around different comment replies, it's more difficult to follow.

Comment: OK, just editted the original post